# how to get this functionality? views: Format options in ctool modal modify field data

Tags: views, chaos-tool-suite

In views module, when we edit view page and add fields to it, there is an option Format:unformatted-list and when we click on unformatted-list, a popup appears displaying radio buttons of grid, table,jump-menu, etc. Choosing any of the radio button, the field adjust themselves in either grid, table, whatsoever the option we choose.

I need the exact functionality of choosing radio buttons, modify my fields display output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module

> Display Suite allows you to take full control over how your content is displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views, comments, user data etc. the way you want without having to work your way through dozens of template files. A predefined list of layouts (D7 only) is available for even more drag and drop fun!

Comment: I am doing everything custom. I cant't use any external module. So far I used chaos modue api to modify form results in popup. But formating fields in various styles is different. Any approach which you can suggest?

Comment: RE "I can't use any external module": You are already using an external module, since the Views module is not part of Drupal core until Drupal 8 comes out.

Comment: I m replicating views module. I am not using Views, just trying to implement views like functionality in my custom module.